# HTML5: Is there any way to control the hardware's framebuffer?

Tags: html

I'm interested in writing lots of HTML5 apps for devices with e-ink (bistable) screens.

But bistable screens exhibit a lot of strange and disconcerting visual artifacts whenever the screen contents change, especially when the browser is drawing and redrawing the layout when a page is loaded or when some javascript modifies the DOM.

So.... is there any way for my HTML code to tell the browser and its operating system to hold off on redrawing anything on the screen until it's done figuring out the new layout?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a dirty hack, but you could think of putting a full page opaque white `div` on the top layer - and then remove it with javascript once the page is fully loaded